# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s^2-4s-2}{\left(s^2+2\right)^2}$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, closed-form

I approached this problem as follow:

$1.$ rewrote $(s^2-4s-2)$ into $(s-2)^2-6$

$2.$ Now break the function into 2 parts:
    $\frac{(s-2)^2}{(s^2+2)^2} + \frac{6}{(s^2+2)^2}$

the Laplace inverse for $\frac{w}{s^2+w^2}$ is $\sin(w*t)$

and the Laplace inverse for $\frac{s}{s^2+w^2}$ is $\cos(w*t)$

but i can't get rid of those powers to the 2 in the question.

please help.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! May be, you could look at Laplace transform of $t \cos(wt)$ and $t \sin(wt)$. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You may use partial fraction
$$
\frac{s^2-4s-2}{\left(s^2+2\right)^2}=\frac{1}{2+s^2}-\frac{4 s+4}{\left(2+s^2\right)^2}
$$
and then make use of a [table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having problems. The answer i come up with is t*cos(sqrt(2)*t) - (sqrt(2)*t + sqrt(2)) * sin(sqrt(2)*t) but my books answer is t*cos(sqrt(2)*t)-t*sqrt(2)*sin(sqrt(2)*t)